# jquery selector ie8 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I've the following statement in jquery which perfectly works on Chrome v.22 and Firefox v.16 but doesn't work on IE8; here's the statement:

first method:

```
$("div[aria-labelledby='myOwnAriaLabelledBy']").css('height',450);
```

second method:

```
$("div[aria-labelledby='myOwnAriaLabelledBy']").attr('id','test');
$("#test").css('height',450);
```

Here's the html, I can't include classes:

```
<div style="display: block; z-index: 1006; outline: 0px none; 
position: absolute; height: 490.333px; width: 600.333px; 
top: 10px; left: 10px;" 
tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myOwnAriaLabelledBy">
```

Does anyone knows if this kind of selector has known issues with IE8?
Thanks

Comment: See the view source and check whether those properties aria-labelledby  are rendered.

Comment: Do you have some HTML to go with that jQuery?

Comment: check difference from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2BaA/) which seems to be working

Comment: I see the fiddle, is it possible that some of the classes causes the issue?

Comment: Try adding a id to that specific div, and use jquery to change the css. If that works, its your selector that is the problem. If not, its has something to do with your other markup or styles.

Comment: even with id selector is working on all browser except ie8

Comment: This might be a long shot, but try this as well: as the height:

'$("div[aria-labelledby='myOwnAriaLabelledBy']").css('overflow','hidden');'

Answer (score 1):

Is your page rendering in compatibility or quirks mode?

I'm not 100% certain but I have a recollection of IE8 support for aria attributes varying depending on the render mode.

Try using a camelCase selector such as

```
$("div[ariaLabelledBy='myOwnAriaLabelledBy']").css('height',450);
```

This *might* only be an issue for vanilla Javascript but it could also be something that is causing jQuery to trip up. I think it's something to do with the '-' character being interpreted as a minus sign.